# Rails console only - Classes don't load (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having the weirdest error. SOMETIMES (usually after a code push), I will SSH into our production RoR servers and load up a console. When that happens, I get a crazy `NameError` error, then I try again and the console loads, but I cant use any of my classes

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-10 /v/w/numanage> rails c -e production
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get': uninitialized constant AdminUser
Did you mean?  Admin (NameError)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `get'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:614:in `constantize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:301:in `get'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:81:in `to'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:76:in `modules'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:93:in `routes'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:160:in `default_used_route'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:70:in `initialize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:331:in `new'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:331:in `add_mapping'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:241:in `block in devise_for'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:240:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:240:in `devise_for'
    from /var/www/numanage/config/routes.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in `draw'
    from /var/www/numanage/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_run_callbacks'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:99:in `run!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:113:in `run!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in reload!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:46:in `tap'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:46:in `block in reload!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `wrap'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:45:in `reload!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:154:in `serve'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-10 /v/w/numanage> rails c -e production
Running via Spring preloader in process 4926
Loading production environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
2.3.1 :001 > User
NameError: uninitialized constant User
    from (irb):2
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /var/www/numanage/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@numanage/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
2.3.1 :003 >
```

The really crazy part is, the puma server starts up just fine and acts like nothings wrong

I'm really at a lost to even debug this, let me know if y'all have any ideas

EDIT:
We are using the devise and ActiveAdmin gems, so the routes.rb:12 is as follows

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

It looks like devise is loading out AdminUser (ActiveRecord model), which is failing for some unknown reason

Comment: Looking through the stacktrace, the only file that looks like it might come from your codebase is this: `/var/www/numanage/config/routes.rb:12` Have you looked at line 12 of your routes file to see what is around there?

Comment: I put the line in the edit

Comment: Cool - have you checked that bundle ran properly on your prod machine?

Comment: Maybe your preloader is the problem. Try again after stopping spring. Kill stray spring processes if any (pgrep -fl spring; pkill spring).

Comment: "You must not install Spring on your production environment. To prevent it from being installed, provide the `--without development test` argument to the bundle install command which is used to install gems on your production machines." https://github.com/rails/spring

Comment: I would fix that asap as spring is not considered safe to run on a production server.